# Зависание терминала при выполнении команды rails generate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Когда пишу rails generate "smth" терминал просто зависает. Mac OS 10.9, Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сгенерировать? А то слово "smth" в доках часто является сокращением слова "something"...

Comment: model, controller. просто пишу к примеру rails g model asfsdf и терминал тупо зависает.
только-что попробовал сделать "rails c", так оно тоже намертво зависло

Comment: это проблемы Мака, а не руби и рельсов ))), измените метки :p

Answer (score 1):

Всей предыстории не знаю, даю общий совет.

```
rails g
```

покажет все доступные генераторы

```
rails g some-generator --trace
```

Позволит отследить на каком этапе зависает система.

Если зависает, смотрите системные логи в Консоли (штатная маковская утилита для просмотра логов).